# How to enable conditional formatting based on if-else condition on 2 previous cells containing dates?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Cell A1, C1 always contains a date. Cell B1 contains either a date or NA or maybe empty. If B1 contains date, then I want C1 to become red on 2nd work day onwards after B1. If B1 is empty or contains NA, then I want C1 to become red on 4th work day onwards after A1.

For example: if A1 = 18/Oct and B1 = 25/Oct, then C1 should become red 29/Oct onwards. if A1 = 18/Oct and B1 = NA, then C1 should become red 24/Oct onwards.

What codes should I put in conditional formatting? Multiple codes are OK.

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpMpC.jpg)

Comment: what code had you tried and not working?

Answer (score 0):

Create a holding column (I had Column **E** as my holding column). Add this formula in `E1`:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK($B1),$B1="NA"), IF(WORKDAY($A1,4)<=$C1, TRUE, FALSE), IF(WORKDAY($B1, 2)<=$C1,TRUE, FALSE))
```

The above formula is based presumptions that your columns are as you listed them in your question. Once you have the above formula in column **E**, paste it all the way to the length of your used rows in column **E**. Then highlight column **C** and create a new rule for conditional formatting. Paste the below formula in conditional formatting

```
=E1=TRUE
```

Hope this helps